# Can you set parameter defaults via Hiera in YAML Bolt Plans?

Tags: yaml, puppet, puppet-bolt

When writing plans in the Puppet DSL I can use a Hiera lookup to assign a default value.

```
plan namespace::myplan (
  String[1] $user = lookup({'name' => 'namespace::user', 'default_value' => 'root'}),
)
```

Is it possible to transfer this to YAML based plans? E.g.

```yaml
parameters:
  user:
    type: String
    description: The user
    default: "<something>"
```

My motivation is to (optionally) reduce the number of CLI arguments by allowing them to be set in Hiera instead.

Comment: Currently no. Automatic Parameter Lookup is not possible in Bolt. The ideas board has an item for a similar feature for tasks: https://portal.productboard.com/puppet/1-puppet-idea-portal/c/11-specify-tasks-parameters-via-hiera